# I have to concatenate two rows in the same table based on the first columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here i'm showing the table

```
Column_1                                                Column_2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GERD                            Onset: 3 Days. Pain scale: 9/10. 
hyperlipidemia                  The diabetes started in 2004 and is controlled.
asthma                          Onset: 6 hours ago.  The initial visit date was 
headache                        Onset: 1 Day.  The severity of the problem is 
hyperlipidemia (comments)       This is a test Comment where i can try
asthma (comments)               Test Comment for the query
```

What i want is this

```
Column_1                                                Column_2
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GERD                            Onset: 3 Days. Pain scale: 9/10.     
    hyperlipidemia                  The diabetes started in 2004 and is controlled. Comment :  This is a test Comment where i can try
    asthma                          Onset: 6 hours ago.  The initial visit date was 
    headache                        Onset: 1 Day.  The severity of the problem is. Comment : Test Comment for the query
```

My SQL statement:

```
 select a.create_timestamp, a.Column_1 as Name, a.Column_2+b.Column_2 as DetailsAndComment from HOPI_ex_ a, HOPI_ex_ b
where a.Column_1+' (comments)' = b.Column_1
```

I'm getting only two rows 
Gerd and hyperlipidemia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're only getting two rows is your where clause that's filtering out rows that don't have a corresponding comment. I think using a left join instead should do what you want. Please try this:

```
select 
    a.create_timestamp, 
    a.Column_1 as Name, 
    case when b.Column_2 is null then a.Column_2 else  a.Column_2 + ' Comment: ' + b.Column_2 end as DetailsAndComment 
from HOPI_ex_ a
left join HOPI_ex_ b on a.Column_1 + ' (comments)' = b.Column_1
where a.Column_1 not like '%(comments)%'
```

Using your sample data the result from the query above would be:

```
Name              DetailsAndComment
----------------- -----------------------------------------
GERD              Onset: 3 Days. Pain scale: 9/10.
hyperlipidemia    The diabetes started in 2004 and is controlled. Comment: This is a test Comment where i can try
asthma            Onset: 6 hours ago.  The initial visit date was Comment: Test Comment for the query
headache          Onset: 1 Day.  The severity of the problem is
```

Comment: @SanuAntony What doesn't work? Could you be more specific please? The results in this SQL Fiddle looks correct to me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f4fea/2